# Mountian Lion Server FTP Access

Tags: ftp, osx-mountain-lion, portforwarding

So I am trying to make FTP access available on my Mountain Lion server. I enabled it and it seems to work, as on the same Mac, with my static I.P. address, I can connect, edit, and remove/add files. But on my other Mac, with the same login, I.P. address, and password, it will not work. It says "530 Login Authentication Failed" on all other computers too. I have port forwarded, and Googled for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had reinstalled Mountain Lion and it seems to have fixed the issue. I'm not sure what was wrong, so I cannot share my fix. Sorry.